# NSMutableDictionary Plist read several

Tags: iphone

I have a PLIST which contains 3 Dictionarys inside.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto1.plist

I try to load this into a dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cars = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto1.plist"]];
```

Further I put these into an NSMutableArray

```
[auto1 addobject:cars];
```

But I can't read out the information. It crashes when I hit the row for this in the tableview.

It works this way but I only read out Item 0. I want to read out all the others as well.

```
NSMutableDictionary *cars = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9358444/auto1.plist"]] objectForKey:@"Item 0"];
```

Do I have to create for every Item a new NSMutableDictionary and then add it to the NSMutableArray auto1? Or is there a way to read all Items in the Plist into a dictionary and array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read out all key/value from the dictionary and add it one by one into your array.

To iterate all key in the dictionary, use

```
[NSDictionary allkeys]
```

which returns an array of key in your dict. Then you can iterate it to get all the values from the dictionary.

If you want to get values only, use

```
[NSDictionary allValues]
```

which returns an array of values in your dict.

You can also consider putting your data in plist like this

```
<key>auto1</key>
<array>
    <dict>
       ...
    </dict>
    <dict>
       ...
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then you can read an array object using

```
auto1 = [dict objectForKey:@"auto1"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Created a new plist like suggested. And it works great.